# Tabulator: Where to add dynamic columns when using AJAX and AutoColumns=true?

Tags: javascript, ajax, tabulator

I'm trying to use the autoColumns feature in Tabulator from data returned from AJAX, then dynamically add column definition info depending on the column, such as filters, sorting, etc.  I've tried adding to both the pageLoaded and renderComplete callbacks, however, it 'overwrites' the filter values typed in the box when it returns the new dataset.  Is there an ideal callback that I can add the code to without having the filters overwritten, or do I need to read the filter values and apply them back?

Here is my header example:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"600px",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    pagination:"remote",
    paginationSize:25,
    paginationSizeSelector:[10, 25, 50, 100],
    paginationButtonCount:5, 
    ajaxSorting:true,
    ajaxFiltering:true,
    pageLoaded:function(pageno){
        //pageno - the number of the loaded page

        var columns = table.getColumnDefinitions();
        //console.log(columns);
        columns.forEach(column => {
            //console.log(column);
            column.headerFilter = "input";
        });
            table.setColumns(columns);
    },
    ajaxURL:"Pagination.php", //ajax URL
    autoColumns:true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From tabulator v4.8 (released first weekend in September 2020) there is a new ***autoColumnsDefinitions*** option that will allow you to define additional column definitions for auto columns

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data:tabledata,
    autoColumns:true,
    autoColumnsDefinitions:[
        {field:"name", editor:"input"}, //add input editor to the name column
        {field:"age", headerFilter:true}, //add header filters to the age column
    ],
});
```

Comment: Is it possible add an extra column when autoColumns is true, e.g. a column that contains edit button? addColumn doesn't seem to work when autoColumns is true. I'm using Tabulator 5.5.